# Infinite number of induced norms

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

While proving that a norm had to come necessarily from a scalar product I have started to wonder about the concept and uniqueness of *induced norm*. My teacher hasn't clarified to me this doubt, saying that in any country in the world what is meant by induced norm is $x\mapsto \sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$.

If $\lambda > 0$ and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is a scalar product, I'll define
$$ \|\cdot\|_{(\lambda)}:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^+\cup\{0\}, x \mapsto \lambda \sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}, $$
which is a norm "induced" (I think) by the scalar product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$. (Is this terminology wrong?) So we can conclude that the number of induced norms is infinite, since $\|\cdot\|_{(\lambda)}\neq\|\cdot\|_{(\mu)}$ for every $\lambda,\mu > 0$ so that $\lambda\neq\mu$. Am I right? I would appreciate your opinion on what does *induced norm* mean, I have not received a formal definition of it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not every norm comes from a scalar product; look after the parallelogram identity.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I think you should read the question. I haven't said that. Having a scalar product, it induces a norm. I am saying that it induces an infinite number of norms.

Comment: You wrote: “While proving that a norm had to come necessarily from a scalar product [...]”. Well, that's actually not true.  You may also note that there is only one *induced norm* by definition.  You are free to deduce other norms deriving from a scalar product but not to call them *the induced norm*.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Yes, I wrote "While proving that A norm had to come from a scalar product [...]" because in that case the norm came from a scalar product. Why there is only one induced norm by definition, $\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$? Could you give me a more detailed explanation and your definition of _the induced norm_?

Comment: I'll put it in answer.

Answer (score 0):

"Induced norm" means, of course, "norm induced from something" (some other norm, a scalar product, etc). In case of matrices, you have a [whole category of induced norms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Induced_norm), where "induced" means "induced from vector norms".

When you introduce a new term, like your norms, the first question to answer is: why are you doing it? What is a novelty here?

Note that

$$\|x\|_{(\lambda)} = \lambda \sqrt{ \langle x, x \rangle } = \sqrt{ \lambda^2 \langle x, x \rangle } = \sqrt{ \langle \lambda x, \lambda x \rangle } = \|\lambda x\|,$$

which is just the Euclidean norm of positively scaled vectors. In other words, your norm has all the same properties as the Euclidean one.

It is like changing the measurement. Let's say you draw your vectors, and denote your coordinates in meters. I.e., the vector $x = (1,2)$ is $1 \text{m}$ to the East and $2 \text{m}$ to the North. Then, $\|x\|$ is the (Euclidean) length of $x$ in meters, while $\|x\|_{(100)}$ is the same length, but in centimeters.

In comparison, if we defined

\begin{align*}
D &:= \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2: 1 = \|x\|_1 := |x_1| + |x_2| \}, \\
C &:= \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2: 1 = \|x\|_2 := \sqrt{ \langle x, x, \rangle } \}, \\
S &:= \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2: 1 = \|x\|_\infty := \max\{ x_1, x_2 \} \}, \\
\end{align*}

then $D$ is a diamond, $C$ is a circle, and $S$ is a square. In case of your norm, it's always a circle, with radius $1/\lambda$. You can read about those norms [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_norm#p-norm).

I suggest you take a look at the aforementioned matrix norms (not just induced ones) to see how different they are.

Don't get me wrong. These norms are new, and you can call them induced norms, since they are norms (they have norms' properties) and they are induced from the Euclidean norm. They just don't seem interesting enough to justify having a special name.

Your teacher is probably right in the way that "induced norm" (not saying from what it was induced) will *usually* meany "induced from the Euclidean scalar product", although -- depending on the context -- this will not always be true.

Comment: I know that both Euclidean and $\|\cdot\|_{(\lambda)}$ are equivalent norms, so there is no special interest. However, using the Euclidean norm as the unique norm that can be induced by the scalar product confused me, that's all. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You can look at the Euclidean norm as a basic case, in a sense that those $(\lambda)$-norms are compositions of scaling and that basic case. Of course, the Euclidean norm can also be seen as a composition of scaling by $1/lambda$ and $(\lambda)$-norms.

Answer (score 0):

It's a question of nomenclature.  In presence of a scalar product $\langle .,.\rangle$ we are able to construct norms which arise from that scalar product; you mentioned the $\|.\|_{(\lambda)}$.  You also know that every norm induces a metric, which generates a topology. As you stated all of the $\|.\|_{(\lambda)}$ are equivalent in the sense that their induced metrics generates the same topology.

So $\lambda$ is topologically speaking of no relevance.  Hence let us choose for the sake of simplicity $\lambda=1$ and *define* that norm as *the* (one and only) *by* $ \langle .,.\rangle$ *induced norm* $\|.\|_{\langle.,.\rangle}$, defined as usual.

Now the only scalar product which induces the Euclidian norm is the standard scalar product.  Different scalar products induce different norms. Does your statement: “using the Euclidean norm as the unique norm that can be induced by the scalar product” still confuses you?

Comment: Ok, good. If by definition the induced norm is $\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$ then there is no problem. I was just wondering if "this norm is defined using scalar product" $\equiv$ "this scalar product induces this norm". Thanks

Comment: You're welcome.